# Twig get an option in url

Tags: twig

in a form i would like modify my url when i change my select option.
When i do this, i have this in my url :

```
?extension-filter=&extension-list=1019
```

And i try to get 'extension-list' for give this parameter in my path.
Something like this is possible ? :

```
<form action="{{ path('my_path', {myoption : app.request.attributes.get('_extension-list') }) }}
```

Comment: have you tried simply app.request.get('_extension-list') ?

Comment: No i have don't tried that... And that work, thank you ! :)

Comment: Hi @Ygg69 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve a param in query string as follow:

```
app.request.get('_extension-list')
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, as i say in comment that work nice :).
But i have an other problem, my path return error because my :
app.request.get('extension-list') is null.
The option url : 'extension-list=1019', run after my action path, so i can't get his value :/.
An idea how get my value before my action path ?